# Not satisfied with original formulation of my question and the answers I received — what steps can I take?

Tags: support, questions, etiquette

I have a question about my UX Stack Exchange post: [Why do the Western European countries use the AZERTY keyboard? What is the historical origin of this layout?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134513/why-do-the-western-european-countries-use-the-azerty-keyboard-what-is-the-histo)

I am not happy with the current quotation posted as "Why haven't France, Belgium, and Luxembourg reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard?" and I really need to get rid of that quotation in the answer before the bounty expires because my question text is now updated to "Why haven't these countries reformed this redundancy by using the QWERTY keyboard instead of the AZERTY keyboard?" without the explicit list of countries.

Comment: I see that there has been some recent edits to this question, and that the text now doesn't have the explicit list of countries. If there's nothing else required I will close this question.